# Spring boot SSL/HTTPS using embedded Tomcat setting, best practice on setting password

Tags: spring-boot, https, jks

We are currently using embedded Tomcat server for running our Spring boot web app. To enable HTTTPS, we are setting the certificate related configuration in a properties file.  Using pom.xml, we package it:

```
  mvn clean install -P PT  # DEV, PT, UAT, Staging, DR, PROD
```

We package the code to a WAR file and run the app from the command line using:

```
  java -jar our-spring-boot-wep.war
```

I have read several online articles on how to configure/enable HTTPS, they all use similar configuration approach as show below, either internally or externally.

```
 # Tomcat connector configuration
 server.tomcat.port=8080
 server.tomcat.ssl.enabled=true
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-alias=cd-something.net
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-store=certificates/cd-something.net.jks
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-password=secret
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
 server.tomcat.ssl.trust-store=certificates/trustStore.jks
 server.tomcat.ssl.trust-store-password=secret
```

Is there a way to hide/encrypt those information such as the password? There are several different environments, DEV, PT, UAT, PROD. Each env has its own certificates/JKS file, What is the best practice to configure it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration properties must be unique by ambient, and place the shared properties inside the war.

Sample :

/resources/application.properties

```
 server.tomcat.port=8080
 server.tomcat.ssl.enabled=true
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-alias=cd-something.net
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

/home/app/config/application.properties

```
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-store=certificates/cd-something.net.jks
 server.tomcat.ssl.key-password=secret
 server.tomcat.ssl.trust-store=certificates/trustStore.jks
 server.tomcat.ssl.trust-store-password=secret
```

by this way acessing the code your only will see the shared properties, and the specific passwords will be only readable if you have access to the server running the app.

I think this native way should work, and there are severals key managers like AWS Key Management that you can explore.